# Passar o nome do item clicado no ListView Android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um código que eu pego o ID do item clicado no `ListView`e passo para um outra `Activity`, mas eu gostaria de pegar o nome clicado e não o ID.

Meu código:

```
if (controle != null) {
    controle.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v,    int position, long id) {
            Intent it = new Intent(layout_projetos_c.this, layout_projetos_c_info.class);
            it.putExtra("idProjeto", id);
            startActivityForResult(it, 1);

        }
    });
}
```

E na outra Activity eu pego o valor do id

```
 long idCli;
 idCli = getIntent().getLongExtra("idProjeto", 0);
```

Como eu posso pegar o nome do item selecionado ao invés do ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Da mesma forma que você passa o id, você poderá passa nome:

```
Intent it = new Intent(layout_projetos_c.this, layout_projetos_c_info.class);
it.putExtra("idProjeto", 10);
it.putExtra("nomeDoProjeto", "Este e o nome do projeto 10");
startActivityForResult(it, 1);
```

Na sua outra `Activity`:

```
String nome;
long idCli;
idCli = getIntent().getLongExtra("idProjeto", 0);
nome = getIntent().getStringExtra("nomeDoProjeto", "");
```

Segue um link que poderá ser útil: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema, no meu caso os itens do listView foram puxados de um Database da tabela de projetos que tem alguns campos, entre eles o campo "nome_projeto" esse campo vai para o list. Suponhamos que eu tenha 3 projetos no List "Projeto_A, Projeto_B e Projeto_C" e ao clicar no Projeto_B eu quero que chame uma outra Activity com os dados do projeto_B(nome no caso) como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: leve seu Id para a Outra Activity, lá vc vai ate o banco e consulta todos os seus dados....